# How to initilaize connection of appium webdriver to a virtual android device that does nothing in Python?

Tags: android, python, automation, webdriver, appium

I need an empty connection of webdriver to a virtual device in order to get an answer whether some application is already installed.

I try the following:

```
caps = {
    'appium-version': '1.4.13',
    'platformName': 'Android',
    'platformVersion': '5.1',
    'deviceName': 'Nexus 5',
    'fullReset': 'false',
    'androidPackage': 'com.android.launcher',
    'appActivity': 'Launcher'
}

driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', caps)
#is_myapp_installed = driver.is_app_installed('com.my.app')
```

but get the following error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Activity used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity)
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the corresponnding app activity and and package name

```
'androidPackage': 'com....packagename of your app',
    'appActivity': 'launcheractivity of your app'
```

As the error clearly states the **activity name** your using doesn't exist which inherently means that ur session is established with the virtual device and its just waiting for a valid activity name to launch.

Let me know if your unable to find the activity of your app

Comment: It should be great if you teach me how to find the activity of app

Answer (score 1):

Answering it newly since this adds another question in addition to your question.

There are multiple ways to find the activity of the app.

u can use aapt command in command prompt : `aapt dump badging "full path to your apk"`

[image]

the first line of the result will give the package name and go to the end of the result and find the launcher activity as shown below

NOTE: inorder for aapt command to work you **android sdk build-tools** folder should be set in PATH variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the proper app activity in code, which will be launched when app launches and appium looks for that activity.

Comment: I know. The question was in another.